# Java: How to print to a scrollable dialog using a void Print() function?

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt, joptionpane

I am trying to print in scrollable dialog box using a void print() function but I can't seem to figure this out. Is it possible to use the function as is?

```
       rslt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                                            tempPanel,
                                            univ.printList,
                                            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: What do you mean, "using a void print() function"? That doesn't parse for me. And regarding, `"Is it possible to use the function as is?"` -- you shouldn't be asking such questions but rather testing them first. We have no idea if such code would work in your program since we don't have your program in front of us. So test it, and if it doesn't work, ask about this, but please whatever you do, provide more information.

Comment: I think you want to actually, I don't know, add something to a displayable component...`System.out.println` prints to the console...Maybe you should spend some more time looking at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Please provide more clarification for community to be able to assist you Rubi.

Comment: I meant to ask if it there is a way that I would use object.printProfessorList() and that the function contents that are printed would be displayed in a dialog box. The dialog boxes of JOptionPane only accept strings.

Comment: `JOptionPane` accepts `Object`, which can be a `JComponent`.  You'd have to change your `printProfessorList` method to return a value or create a different one that added content to the `JOptionPane`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few dozen ways you could do something like this...

Start by taking a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

The following just creates a `html` based list of the items...

```
public void showProfessorList(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(25);
    sb.append("<html>");
    for (int i=0; i < professorList.size(); i++){
        sb.append(professorList.get(i).getName())).append("<br>");
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                                  new JScrollPane(new JLabel(sb.toString),
                                  "Behold",
                                  JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);    
}
```

You could get fancy and use a `JList` instead, but that comes down to your needs...